# Import .Net DLL include dependencies in Python program

Tags: windows, dll, python-3.11

i need help. I want to convert a program which is written in C# into a Python program.
My problem is to include the .Net dll file into the Python program.

First of all I installed the pythonnet lib.

So if i run the command "clr.AddReference('C:\Users\TestDLL\Simatic.dll)', the program is terminated with the exception:

**`The file or assembly "Simatic.dll" or a dependency thereof was not found. The system cannot find the specified file.  Filename: "Simatic.dll"  by System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)  by System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)  by System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadFrom(String assemblyFile, Evidence securityEvidence, Byte[] hashValue, AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)  by System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile)  by Python.Runtime.AssemblyManager.LoadAssemblyFullPath(String name)  by Python.Runtime.CLRModule.AddReference(String name)`**

Until now i tried:

1. to add program Path to the environment Paths (from Python program)
2. to add Path of the dll to the environment Paths
3. Change the Project Path
4. Copy the dll in Project-Folder (I don't know if this is useful because when write in Commandline "where SIMATIC.dll" it prints the folder where the program is installed)

Through dumpbin.exe I know the dependencies but could also not be refer by AddReference().
I didn’t try to call all of them, but the ones I tried didn’t work either.

I need to import a few methods from the dll-File.

I worked with the os Windows 10 and with Visual Studio Code – Python 3.11

So why I couldn’t refer to some dll’s?

Thank you very much for answers!

Answer (score 0):

I could find a solution.

The problem was the missing reference to the dependencies.
So i find out all places of the dependencies and refere with the command

> os.add_dll_directory(path to missing directories)

to these directories.
After this command, the dll was imported without error.